# LINQ PropertyInfo out of range Exception when using List[i] but fine when declared variable tagged

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, propertyinfo

```
public List<string> ExcludeHeaders(IEnumerable<ARandomClass> query, List<string> Excludes)
    {
        var qu = query.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties().AsEnumerable();
        for (int y = 0; y < Excludes.Count; y++)
        {
            qu = qu.Where(c => c.Name != Excludes[y]);
        }

        return qu.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
    }
```

This results in an error : Index out of Range

Whereas this works :

```
public List<string> ExcludeHeaders(IEnumerable<ARandomClass> query, List<string> Excludes)
    {
        var qu = query.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties().AsEnumerable();
        for (int y = 0; y < Excludes.Count; y++)
        {
            var str = Excludes[y];
            qu = qu.Where(c => c.Name != str);
        }

        return qu.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
    }
```

losing my mind over this.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, add you actual code to your question.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual text of the code into your question.

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: This is apparently the well known `for` loop capture problem. Just someone has to find the duplicate.

Comment: does this occur with LINQ?

Comment: Another solution is to just add a single `.Where(c => !Excludes.Contains(c.Name))` or even `.Where(c => Excludes.All(e => e != c.Name))` instead of having the loop.